# Add attribute to pretty url in Yii2

Tags: url, module, yii2

I'd like to add a rule to urlManager but I can't get it work. 
I have path like `/module1/submodule1/mcontroller/maction` and I would like it to be like `/module1/submodule1/mycontroller/myaction/myattribute/1` so that I could have the action `myaction` with GET parameter called `myattribute`. I'd like to have this attribute global, so that it could be any module, any submodule, any controller and any action, and the attribbute could be set like that.
I've tried this

```
'rules' => array(
    '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<myattribute:\d{4}>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<myattribute:\d{4}>' => '<controller>/<action>',

        ),
```

and then in action

```
public actionMyaction($myattribute) {...
```

but none of it worked.

Comment: Youre missing `submodule` in `rules`.

Comment: how can I add submodule there? I've tried <module:\w+><module:\w+> but it gave me an error.

Comment: `<module:\w+>/<submodule:\w+>/...`